# How to use dynamic variables in the twig include

Tags: twig

How to use dynamic variables in the twig include?

I  want to use an include where I pass some variables, and the value of those variables changes as the read comes from the database

```
$product = $twig->load('product.twig');
```

And inside the product.twig, you have {{product_name}}

But in my home.twig file, where the include is, there will be several for with different database read

bringing different results, so how do you make it dynamic?

For me not having to create multiple .twig files on each read from the database

In my variable $products I have all the data to feed the variables that are in the product.twig

However, I will have several variables such as:

$products_demo
$products_promo
etc

home.twig:

```
{% include product %}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your case

$products_demo
$products_promo

I think you can use like at your product.twig

```
{% if product.group == "demo" %}
    {# your code for $products_demo here #}
{% elseif product.group == "promo" %}
    {# your code for $products_promo here #}
{% else %}
    {# another code #}
{% endif %}
```

product.group is array for your product

```
product[0][group] = demo;
product[1][group] = promo;
etc
```